# boost small_vector cannot go back to use stack space

Tags: c++, boost

I have been using `boost::container::small_vector` to store set of objects.

Assuming I am using `boost::container::small_vector<T, 1>`, I understand very well that once the container has more than certain number of elements, it will fall back to use the dynamic storage instead of using automatic storage. However if I resize the small_vector back to 0 element, it seems that there is no way to get the data back to use automatic storage again.

```
int main() {
    typedef boost::container::small_vector<int, 1> V;
    auto print = [](V& v) {
        std::cout << "v.data=" << v.data() << " v.size=" << v.size()
                  << std::endl;
    };

    V v;
    print(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
        print(v);
    }
    v.clear();
    print(v);
    v.shrink_to_fit();
    print(v);
    v = std::move(V());
    print(v);
    v = {};
    print(v);
    V v2;
    v.swap(v2);
    print(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
        print(v);
    }
}
```

prints

```
v.data=0x7fffffff7f18 v.size=1
v.data=0x7fffffff7f18 v.size=2
v.data=0x627c20 v.size=3
v.data=0x627c40 v.size=4
v.data=0x627c40 v.size=0
v.data=0 v.size=0
v.data=0 v.size=0
v.data=0 v.size=0
v.data=0 v.size=0
v.data=0x627c40 v.size=1
v.data=0x627c20 v.size=2
```

How can I make the small_vector to use automatic storage again?

Comment: Why do you want to?  If you've already allocated, you don't gain anything, just use the capacity you already have.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115267/boostcontainersmall-vector-doesnt-seem-to-allocate-in-place

Comment: @Nathan, after shrink_to_fit it would seem logical to be on the original behavior. Cache-locality could be useful reason

Comment: @JVApen But that is wasteful.  Why throw good memory away if you've already spent the cost to get it.  It's still going to be cache efficient.

Comment: @Nathan That's exactly what shrink_to_fit is made for: reduce memory footprint

Comment: It takes time to move elements to the heap once internal storage is exceeded. So if it happened once, the chance is big it will happen again, so why risk wasting time again?